# Get part of canvas

Tags: android, image, canvas, draw

How can i get only the drawn part of a canvas. I want the user to draw on the screen , but display only the drawn part of the view.Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Canvas is used to draw on bitmaps. You can enable the cache and use the command buildDrawingCache and this will return the bitmap the canvas uses. This will the draw parts and the rest will be transparent.